On what macroeconomic modelling the Reform Resolution of the Third Plenum of CPC is based?
The Third Plenum of the Central Committee of the Communist Party of China concluded with the Reform Resolution http://en.qstheory.cn/2024-07/19/c_1006368.htm which (while not available in full AFAK) details around 300 policy issues and which will boost new productive forces.
My question is - are Party institutions or affiliated institutions making macroeconomic modelling before embarking on such resolutions and policy measures? Are such modelling available (I can also read Chinese if someone can suggest sources) and is such modelling different from the macroeconomic modelling of the capitalist societies?
I guess - this can be modelled with the usual DSGE models with additional specification of the technology sector that converts labour and capital into intermediary and final goods. Maybe this sector can be modelled in more detailed way - by considering the array of different technologies and then optimizing for the most beneficial ones? If so, then capitalist societies can check those modelling results and adopt more or less similar policies (of supporting new technologies) as well.
